# Example snippet code for giving output of one reducer to another reducer using Java

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and map-reduce programs. Would be helpful if someone answers my Question

I wanted to write a mapreduce program in which there would be two reducers. Output of one reducer is given to another reducer. To have two reducers, there should be two jobs drivers, Can some one please provide me an example snippet or example code of any mapreduce program in which output of one reducer is given to another reducer along with job's definition code.

Comment: can u share your code which u have tried till..?

Comment: I dont think that you can have two different reducers (one processing the output of the other) in one map reduce job. You simply have to create two jobs when you need further processing of the output.

Answer (score 0):

We can have two mapreduce jobs. The output of the first job can be given as an input to the second job. The mapper of the second job can be just an identity mapper giving the input as the output and we can have our logic for the second job's reducer. These two jobs can be made to run one after the other using JobControl.